# Didn't receive the expected depth of feedback from company after an interview

Tags: interviewing, unprofessional-behavior

I have applied for a software engineer position at a startup. The contact person was one of the co-founders of the company.

Over email, we initially discussed about the compensation, the project and the technology stack. Then, he asked me if I would be up to a coding challenge to check my seniority level. I accepted it, implemented the solution and delivered it in a timely manner.

He answered me the next day stating that

> it's not at the seniority level we would currently need

with no more details.
I asked him for feedback and mentioned one concrete point that I could've done better, then stated there were many *smaller things that signaled a mismatch between my level and their requirements*.

I then asked if he could provide just an example of such *smaller thing*, and he answered that the developer that reviewed the code is on vacation, thus he can't ask him, leaving me without a clear response.

To be honest, I've put quite some valuable time in delivering the coding challenge, and I was expecting them to put just a bit of time in giving me a more specific feedback, yet that was not the case. Were my expectations wrong?

Comment: You put a few hours into it. This person has to put a few hours into it for EVERY person. Do you still feel you are equally vested? He gave you more feedback than most employers will. Right now, I'd take it and run. Give your code sample to some trusted people who you think ARE senior, and ask them what they see.

Comment: Sounds like you got more feedback than most companies give. You weren't right for the position. Time to move on.

Comment: This question shows why companies often give no feedback.

Comment: Post what you did on codereview here (if you are allowed to), you will likely get some valuable feedback how to improve the coding bits.

Comment: Re Zixy's comment. Maybe solve a similar problem and post it on code review. It's not particularly nice to post a companies hiring puzzle straight on the internet.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I mean he should post it on sister site "codereview" where such questions go.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere because judging someone's code is subjective - when you disagree with how someone went about a problem, it usually has to do with subjective values such as how readable it is, whether it performs to a standard of speed that you feel is important, whether you think they overcomplicated it to a degree that you feel is too much.  I think in these situations it's more accurate and amicable to state "your coding style isn't what we're looking for"

Comment: It's honestly unclear to me whether you asking them for more and more details is because you want to disagree with the decision, or whether you just want to learn how to code better. If it's the former, save everyone (including you) some time and energy, and realize you won't win the appeal. If it's the latter, ask yourself why they would take on teaching / code mentorship for someone who's not an employee. The exercise has accomplished its purpose, which was _not_ to serve as a learning experience for you. That said, I'm sorry you didn't get the position. :-\

Answer (score 112):

> Were my expectations wrong?

Yes, your expectations were wrong. In many cases, companies won't give any feedback at all because:

1. in our "sue first" world, it opens the company up to legal action *even if baseless*.
2. they end up wasting their time when a candidate tries to argue about a decision which has already been made, and isn't going to change no matter what the candidate says.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137819/discussion-on-answer-by-philip-kendall-didnt-receive-the-expected-depth-of-feed).

Answer (score 53):

> To be honest, I've put quite some valuable time in delivering the
> coding challenge, and I was expecting them to put just a bit of time
> in giving me a more specific feedback, yet that was not the case. Were
> my expectations wrong?

Yes, your expectations were wrong.

Interviews are about assessing your fitness for the role being offered. They basically told you that you are not a match for the role ("it's not at the seniority level we would currently need"). That's the feedback you needed, and that they needed to convey.

Expecting more specific feedback is a mistake. You might get some occasionally, which could be a pleasant surprise. But often you'll get what you received and no more. Sometimes you'll get no feedback at all.

That's just the way it works. They are trying to fill a role, not help you improve.

Comment: "Sometimes you get no feedback at all". Heck, sometimes they don't even bother to tell you you didn't get the job.

Answer (score 18):

While it would be nice if they gave you the feedback you're asking for, at the end of the day they don't have the time nor the inclination to "mentor" you on what you did wrong, how you could have done better, etc. It's not personal, it's simply a matter of them needing to run a business and fill this position.

Answer (score 9):

One reason they don't want to discuss the challenge with you is because they don't have the time or desire to have any more discussions with a candidate they've rejected. The more detail they reveal, the more likely it is that you will argue that your way is correct or better or whatever. They rejected you, so they want you to go away and leave them alone.

Another reason is because there is likely something very specific that they are looking for with their code challenge, and they don't want to reveal what it is for fear it will somehow become public. That pollutes the candidate pool, and they will have to come up with a new challenge.

Answer (score 8):

> He answered me the next day stating that
>
> it's not at the seniority level we would currently need
>
> with no more details. I asked him for feedback and mentioned one concrete point that I could've done better, then stated there were many smaller things that signaled a mismatch between my level and their requirements.

As other people say, this is more feedback than is normally given. Consider also; they don't want you. The reason they gave is that 'it's not at the seniority level we would currently need', but the real reason might be very different; they may not have liked your T-shirt, your hobbies, they may already have offered the position to the chairmans nephew, or they just didn't like your personality. You'll never know. Just move on to the next opportunity.

Answer (score 6):

Companies should give better feedback than they usually do. I no longer expect reasonable responses to applications or questions.

So: no, you can't expect better.  You deserve better, but expect to be ignored and dismissed.

Comment: I don't agree that companies should provide better feedback. An interview isn't a career coaching opportunity. I'm an idealist, but I'm also a pragmatic realist. In the ideal world, companies would do better at things like this, but at the end of the day this isn't their responsibility and their end goal is filling a role, not giving each candidate career advice or interview coaching.

Comment: @joeqwerty And yet, companies expect employees to give them reasons and rationales when they leave the company to help the company improve and retain talent.  It's a two-way street, unfortunately.  Perhaps if companies were more forthcoming with interview feedback, departing talent might be more forthcoming with the reasons why they're leaving.

Comment: Right, but people might be forthcoming in giving feedback as a disgruntled departing employee if there was a culture of feedback being given as an incoming recruitee.

Comment: I completely disagree. "No" is a complete sentence and doesn't require any explanation. The fact that feedback was given at all was their choice and they are allowed to give as little or much as they want.